# Why is my object property undefined when using it in a if-statement?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to search in an array via for loop

```
      let matrix = [];
      for(let i=0; i<this.row; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<this.column; j++){
            if(this.grid[i][j].name != ""){
              matrix.push(this.grid[i][j].name);
              console.log(matrix);
            }
        }
```

but it does not work. I get the error that `this.grid[i][j].name` is `undefined` although this would work perfectly:

```
      let matrix = [];
      for(let i=0; i<this.row; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<this.column; j++){
            if(this.grid[i][j]){
              matrix.push(this.grid[i][j].name);
              console.log(matrix);
            }
        }
```

I ask whether there is an object and if there is one, then push the name property into the variable `matrix` and here strangely the property `this.grid[i][j].name`is correctly defined but why is it not defined using the property in the if statement?

Comment: Why do you say the `name` property is defined? Give us a sample of the data where you have this problem, so we have a [mcve] and can verify this.

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping me, I found the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this approach

```
 let matrix = [];
      for(let i=0; i<this.row; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<this.column; j++){
            if(this.grid[i][j] && this.grid[i][j].name){
              matrix.push(this.grid[i][j].name);
              console.log(matrix);
            }
        }
```

this way you can check if `this.grid[i][j]` exists then only check for `this.grid[i][j].name`

Comment: That makes sense! There are a also empty entries in my two-dimensional array. I thought they would be ignored but without your condition there would be an error. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :-)